# $|f^{(N)}(z)| \leq |z|^{-N}$ in the punctured unit circle, then $0$ is a removable singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

Take $f$ analytic in $D_1(0)-\{0\}$ such that: $|f^{(N)}(z)| \leq |z|^{-N}$  then $0$ is a removable singularity.

I know that I can write $f(z) = \sum_{n = - \infty}^{\infty}c_n z^n$

Moreover, I can tell that the function $g(z) = z^N f^{(N)}(z)$
is such that: $|g(z)| \leq 1$. But how do I use this information to deduce that either all $c_n$ such that $n < 0$ are zero or find that $zf(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $z \rightarrow 0$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already observed that $g(z)=z^Nf^{(N)}(z)$ is bounded in the unit disc. Then $g$ is already analytic.

Thus, we can write 
$$g(z)=z^{N}f^{(N)}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n}.$$
If 
$$f=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_nz^n,$$
then 
$$f^{(N)}(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n(n-1)\cdots(n-N+1)c_nz^{n-N}.$$

Compare the coefficients. We can see that $c_n=0$ for all $n<0$.

Comment: This makes sense to me! Thank you!

Comment: actually, I am unsure about why $G(z)$ is analytic

Comment: @rannoudanames A standard result tells you that if $f$ is bounded near an isolated singularity then the singularity is removable. (I have simplified my answer.)

Comment: perfect! Should have seen that! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By Weierstrass-Casorati, there are only finitely many $-$ve terms (the singularity cannot be essential). Let the most negative power effectively present be $-n$, and you have a contradiction unless $n=0$, as $|f^{(N)}(z)|$ will go like $|z|^{-n-N}$ for $|z|$ small enough.

Comment: But how do we know that it is not a pole then? We only show that this is not an essential singularity, not that it is removable. And I do not understand your second sentence, do you mind elaborating a bit further?

Comment: As example, suppose it were $z^{-1}$, and $N=2$. Then $f^{(N)}$ would go as $z^{-3}$, which is not less than $|z|^{-2}$.

Comment: Sorry for being slow on this, suppose what were $z^{-1}$?

Comment: Suppose $f$ were.

Comment: In the post, what is a -ve term ?